# How can I disconnect this leaking sprayer hose?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I am helping a family member with some things around the hose and discovered that their kitchen faucet is leaking from the base of the sprayer hose while it is being used.

I would like to disconnect the hose so I can examine and replace the parts as needed. However, I can't figure out how to disconnect the hose from the base of the spray nozzle. If I grip the hose in one hand, and turn the nozzle with the other hand, the nozzle rotates freely. Thus it does not appear to be a threaded connection.

I'm not sure of the manufacturer and model so my attempts at research have thus far failed. Here's a picture of the nozzle where the hose connects to its base:

[image: faucet detail view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know the brand and model of the faucet to ascertain whether that is a connection that is designed to be disassembled. Also, any repair parts like washers/gaskets will most assuredly be proprietary and must be sourced from the maker.

Long gone are the days when faucet components were standardized in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing it in and turning it, this might be what's called a "cam lock" type system.

Comment: Great suggestion, but it didn't work in this case.

Comment: In my (limited) experience, such hoses are not repairable. I wound up with a new faucet/hose assembly.